# Prove that there are no integer solutions to a given equation

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Prove that $ 4x = y^2 + 1 $ has no integers solutions for $(x,y)$

By rules of divisibility:
$$ a \mid b \implies \frac {b}{a} = n $$

for $a,b,n \in \mathbb{Z}$

So let, $ a=4x$, $b=y^2$, and  $ c =1$

then again, by rules of divisibilty:
$$ a \mid (b+c) \implies a\mid b \hspace{5mm}\wedge\hspace{5mm}a\mid c $$

But this gives us a contradiction that for $a\mid c$ breaks the rules for divisibility, 
since there are no integer values of $x$ for which $ a\mid c \implies \frac{1}{4x}$ gives us a integer.

My question is:

Is this a valid proof? or have I made a false statement somewhere?

Comment: the statement $a|(b+c) \Rightarrow a|b \wedge a|c$ is false. In fact $2|(3+5)$ but $2$ does not divide them. To show your claim you could think about the congruence modulo $4$

Comment: One approach you could use is to look at the cases 1) y is even or 2) y is odd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your statment $a | (b+c) \implies a|b \hspace{5mm}\wedge\hspace{5mm}a|c$ is not true, take $a=4,b=3,c=1$ for example.

A better approach is to consider the squares, they are always $0$ or $1 \pmod 4$  You can try the cases for $y$ and find there is no solution.

Comment: Could you please explain on how I could start solving this with modular arithmetic? I am a little confused

Comment: The left side is $0 \pmod 4$. $y^2$ is either $0$ or $1$, so the right side is either $1$ or $2$, so the equation cannot hold.

Answer (score 1):

Note tha $y$ could be in form $4k,4k+1,4k+2$ or $4k+3$ for some integer $k$. Now check each case:

1)$y=4k$, then $y^2+1=(4k)^2+1=16k^2+1$. It isn't divisible by $4$ (but by $x=y^2+1$ it should be).

Can you consider the other cases?